# How can i connect Azure postgres database to pgadmin as im getting time out error

Tags: java, postgresql, azure, pgadmin, azure-postgresql

I have created a database in Azure database in postgreSQL but when i try connect through pgadmin it says unable to connect timeout expired(I'm pretty sure admin and password are correct). Is anyone facing this issue? is there an alternative for pgadmin ?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`pgadmin` works fine against Azure Postgres. A couple things to check:

- Make sure you have a firewall exception in Azure for your local IP address.
- Use the `user@server` format for your username
- Use `server.postgres.database.azure.com`as your hostname
- Make sure to set SSL Mode to `require` in the SSL tab

Good luck!

Comment: Unable to connect to server:

could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
Is the server running on host "myserver.postgres.database.azure.com" (13.96.105.208) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Answer (score 2):

pgadmin works perfectly against Azure database for Postgres. Here's the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/how-to-connect-query-guide) to the docs.

- Add your local IP to your firewall in Azure
- In the Azure portal, navigate to connection strings to get your db credentials
- Use the user@server format for your username
- Use server.postgres.database.azure.com as your hostname
- Maintenance database should be set to postgres
- Ensure that SSL Mode is set to require under the SSL tab

That is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Below settings works for me, you can use below

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I got the timeout all of a sudden, and only after some time I realized it was the VPN that probably blocked a port or so. Once I disabled VPN it worked again. Just something to keep in mind.